# How to get a U16 variable from a U8 array in C?

Tags: arrays, c

I am sending datas from one PIC32 board to another. Please note that the communication between the boards works perfectly.
This is my code:
Main.c

```
BYTE *dataVenantMaitre;
U16 nombreGoutteRecu;
BYTE IdTrameVenantMaitre;
BYTE LongueurDataVenantMaitre;
//Bla Bla

IdTrameVenantMaitre = GetIdTrameVenantMaitre(COM_PERIPH);
LongueurDataVenantMaitre = GetTailleDataTrameVenantMaitre(COM_PERIPH);
dataVenantMaitre = GetDataTrameVenantMaitre(COM_PERIPH);
switch (IdTrameVenantMaitre)
{
        // Bla Bla

        case ID_RFID_SET_NOMBRE_GOUTTES :
            MyMemcpy(&nombreGoutteRecu, dataVenantMaitre, sizeof(nombreGoutteRecu));
            RepondreAck();
        break;
}
```

another.c (the function that gets the data received from the other board)

```
BYTE *GetDataTrameVenantMaitre(U16 num_com)
{
    return dialogue[num_com_to_dial[num_com]].trame.data;
}
```

My problem in here is that: i can successfully get the data that are coded on 1 BYTE, however when trying to get the data "nombreGoutteRecu" which is coded on 2 BYTEs, i only get the first BYTE and the other one is just always 00. I am a starter with C programming, so i couldn't find exactly the problem in here. Please HELP!

Comment: Perhaps the value is small enough that the upper byte will stay zero? What *is* the value? What is it *supposed* to be?

Comment: It's going to be very hard to help you further without knowing what values are supposed to be, or without a [mcve]. For example, what does the `GetDataTrameVenantMaitre` function do? How does it initialize the memory it returns a pointer to? And what does `MyMemcpy` function do? Does it work as intended?

Comment: You could have `nombreGoutteRecu = dataVenantMaitre[0] + (dataVenantMaitre[1] << 8)` or `nombreGoutteRecu = (dataVenantMaitre[0] << 8) + dataVenantMaitre[1]` depending on endianness. But if the "other byte" is always 0 the problem may be in the transmitter, even if that "works perfectly".

Comment: Are you sure the functions return two bytes of data? Or is it possible to get two times one byte each? I suggest to check or print the results of `GetTailleDataTrameVenantMaitre` and `GetDataTrameVenantMaitre`, e.g. `printf("length = %u\n data:\n", (unsigned int)LongueurDataVenantMaitre); for(uint8_t i = 0; i < LongueurDataVenantMaitre; i++) { printf("%02x ", dataVenantMaitre[i]); } printf("\n");`

Answer (score 0):

More universal:

```
U16 getU16(const U8 *u8, size_t pos)
{
    return u8[pos] + (u8[pos + 1] << 8);
}
```

If endianness is the same (on many platforms it will generate more efficient code):

```
U16 getU16_1(const U8 *u8, size_t pos)
{
    U16 val; 
    memcpy(&val, u8 + pos, sizeof(val));
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All good, but thank you anyway. i was actually sending only one byte from the sender board, that's why i only received one byte and the other byte was just filled automatically.

Comment: This means your question doesn't make sense as a reference for others, so I suggest to delete it.